# Mostrar página especifica conforme HTTP_REFERER apenas uma vez por dia

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código em um arquivo: teste.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'site.com.br')
{
echo '<div style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 66px; height: 250px; width: 300px;" id="anuncio"><iframe name="I1" src="http://www.site.com.br/apresentacao1.html" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
} else {
echo('<div style="position:absolute; top:75px; left:85px; height:250px; width:300px; background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px none #000000;" id="anuncio"><iframe name="I1" src="http://www.site.com.br/apresentacao2.html" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
}
?>
```

Se a referência for: site.com.br aparece a apresentação1.html se não for aparece a apresentação2.html.

Eu gostaria também de colocar para se a referência for site.com.br aparecer o apresentação1.html apenas uma única vez por dia, caso já tenha aparecido mostre a apresentação2.html

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Utilize 1 counter, salvando o IP do visitante, que depois de verificares se vem do site `site.com.br` verifica se o IP também já se encontra cadastrado, e se já estiver mostra a página 2. Para tarefas como esta, o uso de `COOKIES` é igualmente necessário, salvando uma ID única para cada visitante(máquina) e posteriormente verificar se o `COOKIE` existe.

Comment: Sério? hehe. Então tá né...

Comment: por ip não é uma boa lógica.. imagine um hotspot num shopping center onde passam 20 mil pessoas num só dia e pelo menos metade se conecta ao wifi.. Todos terão o mesmo IP..   Melhor tentar usando cookies.